# Show a field to logged-in user in Drupal 8 views

Tags: views, theming, 8, users

I have some fields in my views called `products` but only logged in users will be able to see the product `price` field.

I am using `twig`.

I tried using.

```
<div class="menu-items">
  <div class="shopcat-image">{{ uc_product_image }}</div>
  <h3 class="font-bold font-black">{{ title }} </h3>
  {% if logged_in %} <span class="price">{{ price }}</span> {% endif %}
  <div class="item-sku text-center">
  <strong>Item # : </strong> {{ model }}</div>
</div>
```

In custom text

but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the price field globally to anonymous users, consider using something like field permissions.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

This could potentially hide the price in any context it is displayed.

If you need to use twig, other solutions include overriding the templates for the view(s) and/or the field itself.

I would recommend addressing this kind of override from a code side, as it could potentially reveal sensitive information based on the front-end.